# How to sum numbers from a list: "'float' object is not iterable"?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum, integer

I have a list of numbers that I pulled from a dictionary using:

```
amounts = (float(itemDict['TotalAmount']))
print(amounts)
```

A shortened list of the output:

83.31

13.8

280.98

141.69

92.44

369.15

37.4
etc....

but when I try:

```
print (sum(amounts))
```

I get:

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

how do I sum these numbers up? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you using `range`... aren't you just after `print(sum(amounts))` ?

Comment: This is pretty straightforward. The error is telling you exactly what's going on. `amounts` is a `float`.  The `range` function won't accept that as an argument. What is the value of `itemDict['TotalAmount']`?

Comment: The problem is `range()` only takes an `int` but you are giving it `float` values. So you could either convert the argument into `int` if not [you might have to use NumPy](https://pynative.com/python-range-for-float-numbers/)

Comment: I just fixed my original post, the range is not what was throwing it off. It still wont allow me to sum

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you were aiming to do with range() but the sum of those numbers can be obtained simply by: `sum(amounts)` if amounts is a list of floats.  But your sample doesn't correspond to `print(amounts)` (which should look like a list) so there is probably some information missing in your question.

Perhaps you are doing this in a loop on a list of dictionaries, in which case you could add the total in a variable as you go:

```
total = 0
for itemDict in listOfDicts:
    total += float(itemDict['TotalAmount'])
```

or in a comprehension:

```
total = sum(float(itemDict['TotalAmount']) for itemDict in listOfDicts)
```

Comment: Re-reading the Q - the `amounts = (float(itemDict['TotalAmount']))`  sems to imply it's just a single float (else the call to `float` would have failed if it was a sequence/similar) so I'd expect `sum(amounts)` in that case to also fail...